# Apply PredicateBuilder to query a single object property of a list of items

Tags: c#, linq, predicatebuilder

Given the below sample models, I need to query the ITEMS by properties of its owner.
This is Entity Frameworks sets, and I want to do this using LINQ.

```
public class Owner
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //More than 20 other properties
  }

  class Item
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Owner MyOwner { get; set; }
    public int idOwner { get; set; }
    //Several others properties
  }
```

I already have a [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) with the filter of Owners.

I would like to apply this predicate (it is basically the content for where clause) to the `Owner` object, in order to get all the `Item` whose Owner meets the predicate condition.

If the `Owner` were a list of Owners... I could use `.Any(predicate)` but its cardinality is 1.

**EDIT:**

I'm trying to do this to avoid having to get all the `Owners` that fulfill the predicate conditions and then do a `Contains(idOwner)`.

```
db.Items.Where(c => OwnerIdsCollection.Contains(c.idOwner ?? 0));
```

I have seen the massive SQL CASE it creates under the hood for owners that not even have related `Items`.

**EDIT 2 - Predicate:**

```
public static Expression<Func<Owner, bool>> GetPredicate(OwnerCriteria criteria)
{
     var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Owner>();

     if (criteria.Active.HasValue) {
    predicate = predicate.And(p => p.Active == criteria.Active.Value);
     }
     //Several other criteria checkings as above

    return predicate;
}
```

The criteria are obtained from user filters.
Then, I normally use it for querying Owners collection doing `db.Owners.Where(predicate)`;

Now, conceptually, I need to do something like:  `db.Items.Where(x => /*Items filters*/  &&  x.MyOwner.Where(myOwnerPredicate))`

Comment: Is the `Owner` property on `Item` supposed to be of type `Owner` and not `int`?

Comment: Owner is of type Owner, was a mistake. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you simply try:

```
Items.Where(i => predicate(i.Owner))
```

Based on your **EDIT 2**:

```
db.Items.AsExpandable().Where(x => /*Items filters*/ && predicate.Invoke(x.Owner))
```

Comment: Nop.. it seems that as the predicate is created for type Owner, it cannot be applyed for type Items. The way to use it normally is db.Owners.Where(predicate); your idea does not compile.

Comment: I'm trying to do this to avoid having to get all the owners that fulfills the predicate conditions and then do a Contains(idOwner). I have seen the masive SQL CASE it creates under the hood for owners that not even have related 'Items'.

Comment: Can you share how you are actually using your predicate? I can only guess as you haven't provided enough information to understand why your predicate won't work this way.

Comment: Nop... it doen't accept the "&&" either the "x.Owner" as a parameter. I'm thinking it is not possible and I should move to optimize the amount of OwnersIds in some other way.

Comment: If this doesn't work then why was it marked as the answer? I'm in desperate need of a similar solution.